# sand smtp mail php class SMTPClient

Tags: php, utf-8, smtp, smtpclient

I SMTPClient class mail utf-8 post, but I did not do anything!
Please Help me get thank you

```
class SMTPClient
{

function SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $SmtpUser, $SmtpPass, $from, $to, $subject, $body)
{

$this->SmtpServer = $SmtpServer;
$this->SmtpUser = base64_encode ($SmtpUser);
$this->SmtpPass = base64_encode ($SmtpPass);
$this->from = $from;
$this->to = $to;

$this->subject = $subject;
$this->body = $body;


if ($SmtpPort == "") 
{
$this->PortSMTP = 25;
    }else{
$this->PortSMTP = $SmtpPort;
}


}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$to = $_POST['to'];
$from =$_POST['from'];
$subject = $_POST['sub'];
$body = $_POST['message'];
$SMTPMail = new SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $SmtpUser, $SmtpPass, $from, $to, $subject, $body);
$SMTPChat = $SMTPMail->SendMail();
```

I found this code here: http://url.lid.ir/KPyhfU

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: also this is in the old php class format ... the `function SMTPClient` should be changed to `public function __construct`

Comment: All email is sent, but I want to send utf-8 formatted text that need to have utf-8 be readable

Comment: This class will guide you how to change the way that you say?

Comment: Sorry you are not asking a clear question, just pasting code you have found online saying it doesn't work. Please provide details of the actual error you get and how it is not working as you would expect

Answer (score 0):

Change the defintion of the SendMail method in the SMTPClient

```
function SendMail ($charset = "utf-8", $contentType = "text/plain")
{
    if ($SMTPIN = fsockopen ($this->SmtpServer, $this->PortSMTP)) 
    {
        fputs ($SMTPIN, "EHLO ".$HTTP_HOST."\r\n"); 
        $talk["hello"] = fgets ( $SMTPIN, 1024 ); 
        fputs($SMTPIN, "auth login\r\n");
        $talk["res"]=fgets($SMTPIN,1024);
        fputs($SMTPIN, $this->SmtpUser."\r\n");
        $talk["user"]=fgets($SMTPIN,1024);
        fputs($SMTPIN, $this->SmtpPass."\r\n");
        $talk["pass"]=fgets($SMTPIN,256);
        fputs ($SMTPIN, "MAIL FROM: <".$this->from.">\r\n"); 
        $talk["From"] = fgets ( $SMTPIN, 1024 ); 
        fputs ($SMTPIN, "RCPT TO: <".$this->to.">\r\n"); 
        $talk["To"] = fgets ($SMTPIN, 1024); 
        fputs($SMTPIN, "DATA\r\n");
        $talk["data"]=fgets( $SMTPIN,1024 );
        fputs($SMTPIN, "To: <".$this->to.">\r\nFrom: <".$this->from.">\r\nSubject:".$this->subject."\r\n".
        "Content-Type: ".$contentType."; ".$charset."\r\n\r\n".$this->body."\r\n.\r\n");
        $talk["send"]=fgets($SMTPIN,256);
        //CLOSE CONNECTION AND EXIT ... 
        fputs ($SMTPIN, "QUIT\r\n"); 
        fclose($SMTPIN);
    }
    return $talk;
}
```

Comment: I want to use the same class but with utf8 but I can not use this code!

Comment: you have to put in a Content-Type with a charset callout to get UTF-8 going.  This class assembles the mail header for you so the only way to do that is to update the class or overload it. You might want to look into a more modern solution like Zend_Mail.

Answer (score 0):

I found it!
Finally I found it!
It's very easy to add on Code:

```
$this->subject = "=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode(html_entity_decode($this->subject, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')) . "?=".$subject;
```